# How to do a fancy box-plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to plot a box-plot with ggplot2 using the Wage database in the ISLR package. The box-plot is meant to visualize the Wage versus educational level, which is presented in five categories. When I try to use the typical code to generated the box-plot a get the following warning from Rstudio:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3000): y
```

My code is

```r
library("ISLR") 
library("MASS")
setwd("C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/ITSL")
View(Wage)
ggplot(Wage, aes(x=education, y=Wage))+
geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="red", outlier.shape=8, outlier.size=4)+labs(x="Nivel de estudio", y="Salario")
```

I have made other graphics but just with numeric variables, maybe the problem is that now I am using a categorical variable. Any ideas?, thanks in advance and greetings from Chile.

Comment: The variable in the `Wage` dataset from package `{ISLR}` is lowercase `wage` (for your `y=` aesthetic). That should fix your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just needed a lowercase `y=wage` because the column name is `wage` and not `Wage`.

```
ggplot(Wage, aes(x=education, y=wage))+
+ geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="red", outlier.shape=8, outlier.size=4)+labs(x="Nivel de estudio", y="Salario")
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I am so dumb, thanks! take care